# Error Message when using 'boxes' with imgflip's API

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python's Request Module to "Generate a Meme" using *imgflip*'s API, however I am getting the following Error Message when using `boxes` :

`No texts specified. Remember, API request params are http parameters not JSON.`

This is my Current Code:

```py
boxes = [{"text": top}, {"text": bottom}]

params = {
       "template_id": 181913649,
       "username": username,
       "password": password,
       "font": "arial",
       "boxes": boxes
}

meme = requests.post(url="https://api.imgflip.com/caption_image", params=params).json()
```

I have formatted `boxes` to how they want it to be as said in their docs (https://imgflip.com/api)
so i have no idea why it is not working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you're sending something like this:

```
https://api.imgflip.com/caption_image?template_id=181913649&username=username&password=password&font=arial&boxes=boxes
```

I believe this should be [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) encoded:

```
params = {
    "template_id": 181913649,
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "font": "arial",
    "boxes[0][text]": "top",
    "boxes[0][color]": "#ffffff",
    "boxes[1][text]": "bottom",
    "boxes[1][color]": "#ffffff",
}
```

So you should be able to also use [data](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post) (`data=params`) parameter instead.